# Weird characters appearing in the plot legend when using DoHeatmap

Tags: r, legend, heatmap

I was using Seurat to analyse single cell RNA-seq data and I managed to draw a heatmap plot with DoHeatmap() after clustering and marker selection, but got a bunch of random characters appearing in the legend. They are random characters as they will change every time you run the code. I was worrying over it's something related to my own dataset, so I then tried the test Seurat object 'ifnb' but still got the same issue (see the red oval in the example plot).
[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojrhI.png)

I also tried importing the Seurat object in R in the terminal (via readRDS) and ran the plotting function, but got the same issue there, so it's not a Rstudio thing.

Here are the codes I ran:

'''

```
library(Seurat)
library(SeuratData)
library(patchwork)

InstallData("ifnb")
LoadData("ifnb")

ifnb.list <- SplitObject(ifnb, split.by = "stim")
ifnb.list <- lapply(X = ifnb.list, FUN = function(x) {
    x <- NormalizeData(x)
    x <- FindVariableFeatures(x, selection.method = "vst", nfeatures = 2000)
})

features <- SelectIntegrationFeatures(object.list = ifnb.list)

immune.anchors <- FindIntegrationAnchors(object.list = ifnb.list, anchor.features = features)
immune.combined <- IntegrateData(anchorset = immune.anchors)
immune.combined <- ScaleData(immune.combined, verbose = FALSE)
immune.combined <- RunPCA(immune.combined, npcs = 30, verbose = FALSE)
immune.combined <- RunUMAP(immune.combined, reduction = "pca", dims = 1:30)
immune.combined <- FindNeighbors(immune.combined, reduction = "pca", dims = 1:30)
immune.combined <- FindClusters(immune.combined, resolution = 0.5)


DefaultAssay(immune.combined) <- 'RNA'

immune_markers <- FindAllMarkers(immune.combined, latent.vars = "stim", test.use = "MAST", assay = 'RNA')
immune_markers %>%
    group_by(cluster) %>%
    top_n(n = 10, wt = avg_log2FC) -> top10_immune
DoHeatmap(immune.combined, slot = 'data',features = top10_immune$gene, group.by = 'stim', assay = 'RNA')
```

'''

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue other than reinstalling everything?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue myself and while I have solved it by not needing the legend, I think you could use [this approach](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-keep-aesthetic-mapping-but-remove-a-specific-item-from-legend-with-ggplot/52818/3) and use a similar solution:

```
DoHeatmap(immune.combined, slot = 'data',features = top10_immune$gene, group.by = 'stim', assay = 'RNA') +
scale_color_manual(
    values = my_colors,
    limits = c('CTRL', 'STIM'))
```

Let me know if this works! It doesn't solve the source of the odd text values but it does the job! If you haven't already, I would recommend creating a forum question on the Seurat forums to see where these characters are coming from!

Comment: Hi
Thanks for posting this. It does solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

When I use `seurat4.0`, I met the same problem.
While I loaded `4.1`, it disappeared

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer to his question, moreover this question was from a while ago and it appears OP had it resolved